# How to create one Ansible playbook that creates and configures a proxmox lxc container in one go

Tags: linux, dhcp, proxmox

I managed to use then ansible community `community.general.proxmox` to make a role that creates a lxc machine on my proxmox cluster. The problem is that it fails to wait for the machine to start. It says that there is no vm with the name `whatever-name`, but If I run it a second time it fully succeeds. Note that I'm using dhcp to assign the IP, and that after the machine gets an ip from my dhcp server it is reachable by name, because my dhcp also acts as DNS server, and I can reach all my lxc machines by hostname without problem.

Here is the role that creates the machine, and then fails at the last step:

```yaml
---
- name: bla
  debug:
    msg: "{{ api_host }}"
- name: Create new container with minimal options defining network interface with DHCP
  # delegate_to: localhost
  connection: local
  community.general.proxmox:
    api_host: "{{ api_host }}" # The proxmox instance
    api_user: root@pam
    api_password: "{{ proxmox_api_key }}" #Make sure to read from a vault
    node: "{{ proxmox_node }}"
    cores: 1
    disk: "{{ disk_size }}" # GB
    memory: "{{ memory }}"
    nameserver: 192.168.0.110
    password: "{{ password }}"
    hostname: "{{ container_name }}"
    unprivileged: no
    pubkey: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
    storage: "{{ container_storage }}"
    ostemplate: "{{ container_os_template }}"
    netif: '{"net0":"name=eth0,gw=192.168.0.1,ip=dhcp,bridge=vmbr0"}'
    features:
      - nesting=1
    description: created with ansible
    state: present
- name: Start the container
  # delegate_to: localhost
  connection: local
  community.general.proxmox:
    api_host: "{{ api_host }}" # The proxmox instance
    api_user: root@pam
    api_password: "{{ proxmox_api_key }}" #Make sure to read from a vault
    node: "{{ proxmox_node }}"
    hostname: "{{ container_name }}"
    state: started
    unprivileged: no
- name: Wait for the container to start
  connection: local
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ container_name }}.home"
    port: 22
    sleep: 3
    connect_timeout: 5
    timeout: 60
```

How can I make this work in just one run?